# What's the difference between col and color in ggplot

Tags: r

I just started learning R ggplot on Datacamp and it seems that *aes(col=...* and *aes(color =...* can be used interchangeably as they always give the same plots. Is there any difference between col and color??

[with color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHeA5.png)

[with col](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH1o6.png)

Answer (score 2):

From the help for `ggplot2::aes`:

> Details
>
> This function also standardises aesthetic names by converting
> color to colour (also in substrings, e.g., point_color to
> point_colour) and translating old style R names to ggplot names (e.g.,
> pch to shape and cex to size).

In other words, they are interchangeable. ggplot2 converts the base R `col` and the american english `color` into `colour`. (The creator of ggplot2 is from New Zealand, where they primarily use UK spelling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_English#Spelling)